# Build BST from Preorder

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, traversal

Like many newbies, my head blows up from recursion. I looked up a lot of answers/explanations on SO. but I am still unclear on the concept. (This is not homework, I am trying to relearn what I unlearned and recursion was never a string point)

Given a preorder traversal, construct a binary tree. With recursion, it has to be deceptively simple :) but I just can't get it.

I *see* that the order of the arr has to be in the order nodes are inserted. What bugs me is:

1. What if the node already has a left/right? How does this work?
2. How can the recursion insert nodes, in say the following preorder?

   ```
   12, 10, 6, 13
   ```

15 is root, 5, 3 and left

How does 6 get inserted correctly as 10's left child?

```
    12
 10   13
6*
```

Here is the skeleton code:

```
main()
{
   int[] arr = {};
   //make the first node a root node.
   node n = new node(arr[0]);
   buildbst(n, arr, 0)
}

buildbst(node root, int[] arr, int i)
{
   if (i == arr.length) return;

   if (arr[i] < root.data)
      root.left = new node (arr[i]);
   else
      root.right = new node(arr[i]);

   buildbst(root.left, arr, i++);
   buildbst(root.right, arr, i++);
}
```

EDIT:

I just realised, if I pass in the recursive call `buildbst(root.left, arr+i, i++)`
is that the right way? Or am I approaching this all wrong - a mish-mash of dynamic programming and recursion and divide and conquer...

Answer (score 0):

1. It can't already have a left / right child. You call it for the root, which has no children to start. Then you call it for the left child and create children where appropriate and call the function for those children and so on. You never visit the left child again once you go right and you can't get to a node from a function called on its child (since there is no connection up the tree, except the recursion stack).
2. This is what should happen when given `12, 10, 6, 13`:

   - Creates the root `12`
   - Calls `buildbst(node(12), arr, 1)`

     - Create `node(12).left = node(10)`
     - Calls `buildbst(node(10), arr, 2)`

       - Create `node(10).left = node(6)`
       - Calls `buildbst(node(6), arr, 3)`

         - `13 > 12`, must be right child of `12`, so do nothing
       - `13 > 12`, must be right child of `12`, so do nothing
     - Create `node(12).right = node(13)`
     - Calls `buildbst(node(13), arr, 3)`

       - Oh look, no more elements, we're done.

The above is not what will happen with your code for 2 reasons:

- Your code will only create either a left or a right child, not both (because of the `if-else`))
- Your code doesn't have the `must be right child of '12'` check, which is a little complex

The below code should cover it.

```
node buildbst(int[] arr)
{
   node n = new node(arr[0]);
   // 9999999999 is meant to be > than the biggest element in your data
   buildbst(n, arr, 1, 9999999999);
   return node;
}

int buildbst(node current, int[] arr, int i, int biggestSoFar)
{
    if (i == arr.length) return i;

    // recurse left
    if (arr[i] < current.data)
    {
      current.left = new node(arr[i++]);
      i = buildbst(current.left, arr, i, current.data);
    }

    // recurse right
    if (i < arr.length && arr[i] < biggestSoFar)
    {
      current.right = new node(arr[i++]);
      i = buildbst(current.right, arr, i, biggestSoFar);
    }

    return i;
}
```

**Explanation:**

The purpose of `biggestSoFar` is to prevent:

```
    15                          15
   /                            /\
  5     versus (the correct)   5  20
 / \                          /
1   20                       1
```

When recursing left from `15` for example, we need to stop processing elements as soon as we get an element `> 15`, which will happen when we get `20`. Thus we pass `current.data` and stop processing elements if we get a bigger value.

When recursing right from `5` for example, we need to stop processing elements as soon as we get an element `> 15`, which will happen when we get `20`. Thus we pass `biggestSoFar` and stop processing elements if we get a bigger value.

Comment: We would have to keep the lower and upper limits at each node. Just keeping the upper limits would not serve the purpose. In the given example if 25 was the root above 15, then the construction would be incorrect using the above algorithm.

Comment: @noddy Once you go right, all elements must be bigger than that element, otherwise the tree is invalid, thus keeping the lower limit is not necessary. When passed `25,15,5,1,20`, when `i` = 4, `arr[i]` = 20 and `biggestSoFar` = 25, then `arr[i] < biggestSoFar` and it will create `20` to the right of `15`, as required. Though I did have a different bug in my code, which I fixed.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for and it helped me fix some extra code I had in mine! Like removing the minAllowed :) that was added when going right